# ionic4 - "firebase-analytics" and "admob-free" cause error in Android

Tags: cordova, admob, cordova-plugins, ionic4, firebase-analytics

I am using Ionic4. All was working perfect until I had add new plugin. Please have a look at my steps:-

1.I add below plugins, then it works.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics

npm install @ionic-native/firebase-analytics

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics

npm install @ionic-native/google-analytics

cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=+

cordova plugin add cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release  --variable FIREBASE_VERSION=+

cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable FIREBASE_VERSION=+

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

2.I add below plugin, then it cause "IllegalStateException"

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID=“ca-xxxx”

npm install @ionic-native/admob-free
```

3.Below is cordova plugin list

```
cordova-admob-sdk 0.24.1 "AdMob SDK"
cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release 4.0.0 "cordova-android-firebase-    gradle-release"
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 4.0.0 "cordova-android-play-    services-gradle-release"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-admob-free 0.27.0 "Cordova AdMob Plugin"
cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 4.0.1 "FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.6 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-speechrecognition 1.1.2 "Speech Recognition"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.3 "SocialSharing"
cordova-promise-polyfill 0.0.2 "cordova-promise-polyfill"
cordova-support-android-plugin 1.0.1 "cordova-support-android-plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.3.2 "cordova-support-google-services"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
```

Answer (score 0):

I input below command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID=“ca-xxxx”
```

But below command is correct.And it works.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID=ca-xxxx
```